# How do I print debug messages in the Google Chrome JavaScript Console?

Tags: javascript, console, debugging, google-chrome

How do I print debug messages in the Google Chrome JavaScript Console?

Please note that the JavaScript Console is not the same as the JavaScript Debugger; they have different syntaxes AFAIK, so the **print** command in JavaScript Debugger will not work here. In the JavaScript Console, `print()` will send the parameter to the printer.

Answer (score 605, accepted):

Executing following code from the browser address bar:

```
javascript: console.log(2);
```

successfully prints message to the "JavaScript Console" in Google Chrome.

Comment: Just realized, `console.log()` is awesome for js debugging ... I often forget using it in practice.

Comment: How long can one of these "outputs" be? Upvote by the way, this was really helpful

Comment: @dbrin this is fine for development, however any `console.log()` code should be removed from production code before deployment.

Comment: @Sebas `Console.Log`'s should be removed from production code before deployment because if not, these messages will be logging to your users' JavaScript console. Whilst they're unlikely to see it, it is taking up memory space on their device. Also, depending on the content of the Log, you're potentially telling people how to hack/reverse engineer your app.

Answer (score 167):

Improving on Andru's idea, you can write a script which creates console functions if they don't exist:

```
if (!window.console) console = {};
console.log = console.log || function(){};
console.warn = console.warn || function(){};
console.error = console.error || function(){};
console.info = console.info || function(){};
```

Then, use any of the following:

```
console.log(...);
console.error(...);
console.info(...);
console.warn(...);
```

These functions will log different types of items (which can be filtered based on log, info, error or warn) and will not cause errors when console is not available. These functions will work in Firebug and Chrome consoles.

Comment: Thanks for that. Wouldn't the code be tighter if you ran the "if" once, like `if (!window.console) {` and then put everything inside brackets? Right now you're evaluating the same stuff four times.

Comment: No, b/c just having window.console doesn't guarantee that you'll have a window.console.log or .warn &c

Comment: Just be careful because if this script is loaded with the page and the console window is not open, it will create the 'dummy' console which can prevent the real console from working if you open the console *after* the page is loaded. (at least this is the case in older versions of firefox/firebug and chrome)

Comment: I have additions to this, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580824/60518) below

Comment: This will make Chrome abort with a "TypeError: Illegal Invocation" error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply

Comment: No, this will **not** make chrome abort with a TypeError. The linked question above is about calling with **this**. The code above doesn't do that and will work just fine in Chrome

Answer (score 49):

Just add a cool feature which a lot of developers miss:

```
console.log("this is %o, event is %o, host is %s", this, e, location.host);
```

This is the magical `%o` dump *clickable and deep-browsable* content of a JavaScript object. `%s` was shown just for a record.

Also this is cool too:

```
console.log("%s", new Error().stack);
```

Which gives a Java-like stack trace to the point of the `new Error()` invocation (including *path to file and line number*!).

Both `%o` and `new Error().stack` are available in Chrome and Firefox!

Also for stack traces in Firefox use:

```
console.trace();
```

As https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console says.

Happy hacking!

**UPDATE**: Some libraries are written by bad people which redefine the `console` object for their own purposes. To restore the original browser `console` after loading library, use:

```
delete console.log;
delete console.warn;
....
```

See Stack Overflow question *[Restoring console.log()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089443)*.

Comment: One other I just discovered: console.dir   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir

Answer (score 17):

Just a quick warning - if you want to test in Internet Explorer without removing all console.log()'s, you'll need to use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) or you'll get some not particularly friendly errors.

(Or create your own console.log() which just returns false.)

Comment: I avoid cross browser errors like such: if (console) console.log()

Comment: If you open the developer tools in IE (F12), the `console` object is created and exists till you close that browser instance.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a short script which checks if the console is available. If it is not, it tries to load [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) and if Firebug is not available it loads Firebug Lite. Now you can use `console.log` in any browser. Enjoy!

```
if (!window['console']) {

    // Enable console
    if (window['loadFirebugConsole']) {
        window.loadFirebugConsole();
    }
    else {
        // No console, use Firebug Lite
        var firebugLite = function(F, i, r, e, b, u, g, L, I, T, E) {
            if (F.getElementById(b))
                return;
            E = F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;
            E = E ? F[i + 'NS'](E, 'script') : F[i]('script');
            E[r]('id', b);
            E[r]('src', I + g + T);
            E[r](b, u);
            (F[e]('head')[0] || F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);
            E = new Image;
            E[r]('src', I + L);
        };
        firebugLite(
            document, 'createElement', 'setAttribute', 'getElementsByTagName',
            'FirebugLite', '4', 'firebug-lite.js',
            'releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png',
            'https://getfirebug.com/', '#startOpened');
    }
}
else {
    // Console is already available, no action needed.
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In addition to [Delan Azabani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2757552/60518), I like to share my `console.js`, and I use for the same purpose. I create a noop console using an array of function names, what is in my opinion a very convenient way to do this, and I took care of Internet Explorer, which has a `console.log` function, but no `console.debug`:

```
// Create a noop console object if the browser doesn't provide one...
if (!window.console){
  window.console = {};
}

// Internet Explorer has a console that has a 'log' function, but no 'debug'. To make console.debug work in Internet Explorer,
// We just map the function (extend for info, etc. if needed)
else {
  if (!window.console.debug && typeof window.console.log !== 'undefined') {
    window.console.debug = window.console.log;
  }
}

// ... and create all functions we expect the console to have (taken from Firebug).
var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
    "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i){
  if(!window.console[names[i]]){
    window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Or use this function:

```
function log(message){
    if (typeof console == "object") {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.constructor === Object && (log = m => console.log(m))`

Answer (score 7):

Here's my console wrapper class. It gives me scope output as well to make life easier. Note the use of `localConsole.debug.call()` so that `localConsole.debug` runs in the scope of the calling class, providing access to its `toString` method.

```
localConsole = {

    info: function(caller, msg, args) {
        if ( window.console && window.console.info ) {
            var params = [(this.className) ? this.className : this.toString() + '.' + caller + '(), ' + msg];
            if (args) {
                params = params.concat(args);
            }
            console.info.apply(console, params);
        }
    },

    debug: function(caller, msg, args) {
        if ( window.console && window.console.debug ) {
            var params = [(this.className) ? this.className : this.toString() + '.' + caller + '(), ' + msg];
            if (args) {
                params = params.concat(args);
            }
            console.debug.apply(console, params);
        }
    }
};

someClass = {

    toString: function(){
        return 'In scope of someClass';
    },

    someFunc: function() {

        myObj = {
            dr: 'zeus',
            cat: 'hat'
        };

        localConsole.debug.call(this, 'someFunc', 'myObj: ', myObj);
    }
};

someClass.someFunc();
```

This gives output like so in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29):

```
In scope of someClass.someFunc(), myObj: Object { dr="zeus", more...}
```

Or Chrome:

```
In scope of someClass.someFunc(), obj:
Object
cat: "hat"
dr: "zeus"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 6):

Personally I use this, which is similar to tarek11011's:

```
// Use a less-common namespace than just 'log'
function myLog(msg)
{
    // Attempt to send a message to the console
    try
    {
        console.log(msg);
    }
    // Fail gracefully if it does not exist
    catch(e){}
}
```

The main point is that it's a good idea to at least have some practice of logging other than just sticking `console.log()` right into your JavaScript code, because if you forget about it, and it's on a production site, it can potentially break all of the JavaScript code for that page.

Comment: why not `if(windows.console) console.log(msg)`?

Comment: `window.console` you mean. the only time the try would be useful is if an Error was thrown (if console.log wasn't a function) since console was redefined. Doing `window.console && window.console.log instanceof Function` would be more useful.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `console.log()` if you have a debugged code in what programming software editor you have and you will see the output mostly likely the best editor for me (Google Chrome). Just press <kbd>F12</kbd> and press the Console tab. You will see the result. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 4):

I've had a lot of issues with developers checking in their console.() statements. And, I really don't like debugging Internet Explorer, despite the fantastic improvements of [Internet Explorer 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) and [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012), etc.

So, I've overridden the console object itself... I've added a __localhost flag that only allows console statements when on localhost. I also added console.() functions to Internet Explorer (that displays an alert() instead).

```
// Console extensions...
(function() {
    var __localhost = (document.location.host === "localhost"),
        __allow_examine = true;

    if (!console) {
        console = {};
    }

    console.__log = console.log;
    console.log = function() {
        if (__localhost) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined" && typeof console.__log === "function") {
                console.__log(arguments);
            } else {
                var i, msg = "";
                for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                    msg += arguments[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    };

    console.__info = console.info;
    console.info = function() {
        if (__localhost) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined" && typeof console.__info === "function") {
                console.__info(arguments);
            } else {
                var i, msg = "";
                for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                    msg += arguments[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    };

    console.__warn = console.warn;
    console.warn = function() {
        if (__localhost) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined" && typeof console.__warn === "function") {
                console.__warn(arguments);
            } else {
                var i, msg = "";
                for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                    msg += arguments[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    };

    console.__error = console.error;
    console.error = function() {
        if (__localhost) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined" && typeof console.__error === "function") {
                console.__error(arguments);
            } else {
                var i, msg = "";
                for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                    msg += arguments[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                alert(msg);
            }
        }
    };

    console.__group = console.group;
    console.group = function() {
        if (__localhost) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined" && typeof console.__group === "function") {
                console.__group(arguments);
            } else {
                var i, msg = "";
                for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                    msg += arguments[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                alert("group:\r\n" + msg + "{");
            }
        }
    };

    console.__groupEnd = console.groupEnd;
    console.groupEnd = function() {
        if (__localhost) {
            if (typeof console !== "undefined" && typeof console.__groupEnd === "function") {
                console.__groupEnd(arguments);
            } else {
                var i, msg = "";
                for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                    msg += arguments[i] + "\r\n";
                }
                alert(msg + "\r\n}");
            }
        }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Clever way to leave hundreds of debug output messages in the code,
    /// but not see _everything_ when you only want to see _some_ of the
    /// debugging messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// To enable __examine_() statements for sections/groups of code, type the
    /// following in your browser's console:
    ///       top.__examine_ABC = true;
    /// This will enable only the console.examine("ABC", ... ) statements
    /// in the code.
    /// </remarks>
    console.examine = function() {
        if (!__allow_examine) {
            return;
        }
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            var obj = top["__examine_" + arguments[0]];
            if (obj && obj === true) {
                console.log(arguments.splice(0, 1));
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Example use:

```
    console.log("hello");
```

Chrome/Firefox:

```
    prints hello in the console window.
```

Internet Explorer:

```
    displays an alert with 'hello'.
```

For those who look closely at the code, you'll discover the console.examine() function. I created this years ago so that I can leave debug code in certain areas around the product to help troubleshoot [QA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_assurance)/customer issues. For instance, I would leave the following line in some released code:

```
    function doSomething(arg1) {
        // ...
        console.examine("someLabel", arg1);
        // ...
    }
```

And then from the released product, type the following into the console (or address bar prefixed with 'javascript:'):

```
    top.__examine_someLabel = true;
```

Then, I will see all of the logged console.examine() statements. It's been a fantastic help many times over.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful idea. Was quite inspiring. From your examine function, I unwittingly went on to the idea of scope for debugging php. mydebug_on('somescope'), mydebug('somescope',$data) etc. Now I can turn on/off subject selective debugging and logging for php code. And just like regular linux programs it can log in a standard regular verbose etc flavor. Quite a nice idea indeed!

Answer (score 3):

Simple [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7) and below [shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_%28computing%29) that preserves line numbering for other browsers:

```
/* Console shim */
(function () {
    var f = function () {};
    if (!window.console) {
        window.console = {
            log:f, info:f, warn:f, debug:f, error:f
        };
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.debug("");
```

Using this method prints out the text in a bright blue color in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Improving further on ideas of Delan and Andru (which is why this answer is an edited version); console.log is likely to exist whilst the other functions may not, so have the default map to the same function as console.log....

You can write a script which creates console functions if they don't exist:

```
if (!window.console) console = {};
console.log = console.log || function(){};
console.warn = console.warn || console.log;  // defaults to log
console.error = console.error || console.log; // defaults to log
console.info = console.info || console.log; // defaults to log
```

Then, use any of the following:

```
console.log(...);
console.error(...);
console.info(...);
console.warn(...);
```

These functions will log different types of items (which can be filtered based on log, info, error or warn) and will not cause errors when console is not available. These functions will work in Firebug and Chrome consoles.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is old, and has good answers, I want to provide an update on other logging capabilities.

You can also print with groups:

```
console.group("Main");
console.group("Feature 1");
console.log("Enabled:", true);
console.log("Public:", true);
console.groupEnd();
console.group("Feature 2");
console.log("Enabled:", false);
console.warn("Error: Requires auth");
console.groupEnd();
```

Which prints:

[image]

This is supported by all major browsers according to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/group):
[image]