# how to console with google chrome

Tags: php

I want to console with Google chrome when I test my website. If I found some error, I want to see it in Developer > Developer Tools > Console using link. Now, my Google Chrome doesn't shown error link. eg. when I query from database, and I show this query using jQuery but it has some error. But console can't output this error link and can't give me something.php code.

Comment: You might also find this useful: [How-to-terminate-script-execution-when-debugging-in-Google-Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134723/how-to-terminate-script-execution-when-debugging-in-google-chrome#answer-29392465)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's Developer Tools only for client side problems only. If you'd like to debug PHP in your browser you could use [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), the Firebug extension.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks.
I mean that
How to get RID of XHR messages on console??
My chrome version is 5.0.396.0.

Comment: I mean please look at here
"http://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=3129569015484012593&name=Screen+shot+2010-06-23+at+7.30.38+PM.png&token=5fb542838aa3447daaeab233686815e4&inline=1"
I want to show this console link in my browser.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe you should look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-to-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console

Answer (score 9):

If you want to debug PHP errors/exceptions in Google Chrome console, try to use [PHP Console](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef) extension. It's awesome!