# How to disable JavaScript in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug the features of a website when users disable their JavaScript. I was wondering how do you disable JavaScript for a page from the Google Chrome DevTools?

Comment: The command menu, which has been around since about April 2016, is probably faster than the older workflows that relied on going into DevTools settings: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40727332/1669860

Comment: I am adding this as a comment because it does not answer the OP question, but it answers a related question that I was looking for (I found this, but not an answer to my question). If you want to turn off only a **specific script**, for example a slide show, because it is impeding efforts of adjusting CSS styles in Dev tools, do the following: Go `Sources` tab. Navigate file tree to find the script (usually you want to choose the minimized version). Click the **||** `pause` button. Now you can go back to the Elements tab to inspect/edit CSS without HTML (& scroll location) constantly changing.

Answer (score 674, accepted):

Click the **gear** icon in the corner of the Developer Tools, click `Settings`, then under `Debugger`, check `Disable Javascript`, as shown in the following video:

[image]

Comment: It is not working for me too. @Matt did you find a solution? I am trying to avoid a page from auto reloading using javascript and chrome developer tools disable JavaScript is not working.

Comment: @Krishna: It's probably auto-reloading without Javascript.

Comment: Yes. Looked at the source and was meaning to update it here a few hours back, but got held up. It is using meta refresh.

Comment: If still not working, consider Ctrl+Shift+n, Open new Chrome window in incognito mode.

Comment: @PaintyJoy, thanks for that tip. For some reason my "Disable Javascript" is being buggy when I refresh... "Incognito Mode" -> F12 > Settings > "Disable Javascript" -> Refresh works! Would love to know WHY it's not working in regular mode. I haven't found any tickets for this issue. Seems to only happen to certain users.

Comment: @MattParkins Chrome Developer Tool seem to break every now and then ("complex" code I guess ^^). So use Alex's answer isntead http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405449/759452

Comment: I know this is an older post, but it was the only thing that helped me with a google search of `google chrome 45.0.2454.85 incognito disable javascript` .. and I had to do it through DDG at that .. just wanted to note that as of a fresh install of Chrome 45.0.2454.85 the 'gear icon' does not show anywhere on the screen (in regular or incognito mode) and I had to hit `F12` to get the to icon .. FYI to others that might have the same issue

Comment: @txtechhelp: The question is specifically asking how to disable Javascript _from the dev tools_.  Clarified.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot that shows the location of the *"gear"* icon in the lower-right corner of the Developer Tools? For example, [here is a screenshot of the Developer Tools that shows there is no *"gear"* icon](http://i.imgur.com/OjQHSaj.png).

Comment: There is no gear icon anymore,  they removed it at some point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Click the `...` menu in the corner, then Settings.

Comment: Yeah, they moved the cheese around. Found it in a newer answer. :)

Comment: You will now find the "Disable JavaScript" option on the right side in de Preferences menu. Headline is: "Debugger"

Comment: It doesn't always work. I can't stop the javascript of Chrome Extensions even if I disable it both on the page and on the extension inspect view.

Answer (score 215):

**Update August 2020**

1. Developer Tools (F12)
2. Click the Gear icon

[image: Settings]

3. Should open the Preference tab
4. Disable Javascript option is on the far right

[image: Disable JS option]

**Original answer**

1. Developer Tools (F12)
2. Three vertical dots in upper right
3. Settings
4. Under the "Preferences" tab on the left

[image: Preferences section]

5. There will be a "Debugger" section with the option (probably on far right)

[image: Disable check box]

Comment: Correct, they made it heck lots harder to find, no idea why.

Comment: Maybe it's less important now so many web apps require JavaScript? It's so frustrating because I have to keep testing graceful degradation so I need to continually switch back and forth.

Answer (score 111):

Official documentation: [Disable JavaScript With Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/disable)

There's now a command menu built into DevTools that makes it easier to disable JavaScript. This has been around as of April 2016 or so.

1. [Open DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#open).
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows, Linux) to open the Command Menu. Make sure that your cursor's focus is on the DevTools window, not your browser viewport.
3. Type `Disable JavaScript` (or some version of that... it's a fuzzy search) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use the `Enable JavaScript` command when you want to turn it back on.

[image: disabling js via command menu]

Comment: have devtools active before trying this.

Answer (score 39):

`chrome://settings/content` Javascript/Manage Exceptions

Answer (score 20):

This extension makes it faster (I am the author) : **[Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje)**

It is open source: https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher

Comment: Great tip, works superduperly — quick and simple and reloads the page too! Instant on and offness

Comment: Bad thing is that it reloads the page, while I need it not to do so.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph it appears to have been addressed, there is now a Auto-Refresh option.  Maxime, it would be good to say in the answer that you are the author. The only big missing thing is a shortcut or documentation for it: https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher/issues/32

Comment: Thanks @CiroSantilli新疆棉花TRUMPBANBAD, this is fixed.

Answer (score 12):

You can also run Chrome with JavaScript disabled by default by using the flag:

```
-disable-javascript
```

You would use this for example by running Chrome like this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome" -disable-javascript
```

Comment: `-disable-javascript` doesn't work with google-chrome-stable-51.0.2704.106-1.x86_64.

Comment: Try `--blink-settings=scriptEnabled=false` instead

Comment: Source: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/out/Debug/gen/third_party/blink/renderer/core/settings_macros.h

Answer (score 11):

The quickest way is problably this one:

- F12 to open the dev console
- ctrl + shift + p to open the command tool (windows)
- Type 'disable javascript' and hit enter

Answer (score 7):

On OSX, I had to click the triple vertical dots, and uncheck a box in the settings section. Which can also be opened with `f1`

Answer (score 6):

Using only the keyboard at least for Windows 10:

- <kbd>F12</kbd>, shows Developer Tools
- <kbd>F1</kbd>, shows Settings
- <kbd>tab</kbd>, moves to the "Disable Javascript" check box
- <kbd>space</kbd>, toggles the option
- <kbd>esc</kbd>, hides Settings

Comment: Works on ubuntu too.

Answer (score 4):

**The fast way**:

1) just click on **CTRL + SHIFT + P**

2) fill the field by the 3 letters **dis** and will appear this box and select the item **Disable Javascript**

[image: disable javascript]
.

that's all folks!

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X:

- Preferences
- Show advanced settings
- Press the "content settings" button
- Scroll to the "JavaScript" section
- Check the checkbox in front of "Do not allow any site to run JavaScript"

The [Chrome Quick JavaScript Switcher extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje) is a lot easier though :-)

Answer (score 3):

- Go to options (Windows: three vertical dots in the top right) -> Settings, or hit F1.
- In the General section you find "disable JavaScript"

The gear icon is no longer part of developer tools. Since Chome 30.0 it is not even possible to bring it back ([In Google Chrome Developer Tools, the toolbar icons disappeared. What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348919/in-google-chrome-developer-tools-the-toolbar-icons-disappeared-what-gives))

Answer (score 3):

To temporarily block JavaScript on a domain :

1. Click on the Button left to the address on the address bar (which says `View site information`)
2. In the drop-down next to `JavaScript`, select `Always block on this site`
3. Reload Page

Answer (score 3):

- Click the ⋮ menu in the corner of the Developer Tools, click Settings
- Click on Advanced at the bottom
- Click on Content Settings
- Click on JavaScript
- Switch off

Answer (score 3):

### Full and fast instructions for Chrome browsers (Opera incl.)

**The first way**

1. If Developer Tools aren't open then press <kbd>**F12**</kbd> key on keyboard to show the Developer Tools. In Opera browser you have to use key combination <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**i**</kbd> on keyboard to open it.
2. To show the settings just press <kbd>**F1**</kbd> key on keyboard. The Developer Tools window must be focused when you are doing it. Or if you want to open the settings with the mouse then you have to click on `⋮` button in the top right corner of the Developer Tools, then click `Settings` in the menu.

Then you have to scroll down the settings window to bottom and then you will see the checkbox for disabling JavaScript like follows:

[image: disable JavaScript in chrome developer tools]

Just click on this checkbox and push <kbd>**esc**</kbd> key on keyboard for hide the settings. If you want to enable it then you have to do the same way again.

**The second way**

1. If Developer Tools aren't open then open it like in the first way is described.
2. Press the key combination <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**P**</kbd> (for Windows or Linux) or <kbd>**Cmd (⌘)**</kbd> + <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**P**</kbd> (for Mac) to open the Command Menu. Be sure that the focus is on the DevTools window.
3. Type there "Disable JavaScript" and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click it with the mouse. If you want to turn back the enanled JS then open the Command Menu again and type there "Enable JavaScript" and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click it with the mouse. You could also write just only "JavaScript" or "Java" there and then choose it with the mouse.

[image: disable JavaScript in chrome developer tools]

**If all this does not work**

For some reason it is possible that it does not work. I this case open a new empty site in "Incognito Mode" and do all this there.

**The quickest way**

In Chrome Web Store or on Opera Addon site you can find and install extensions which do it per one click. Just search `"Javascript Switcher"`:

- [For Chrome browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Javascript%20Switcher)
- [For Opera browser](https://addons.opera.com/en/search/?query=Javascript%20Switcher)

Answer (score 2):

Press **F8** for temporarily freezing / unfreezing JS (with DevTools open).

This is very useful for debugging UI issues on elements that may lose focus if you click or press anything outside of that element. (Chrome 71.0.3578.98, Ubuntu 18.10)

Answer (score 1):

Paste it: chrome://settings/content

Go to "Javascript" section and disable it.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? The user has to go down to the JavaScript section and choose "Block".

Answer (score 0):

```
Chrome://chrome/settings/Privacy/Content settings/JavaScript
```

and there you can PASTE your website's URL in `Manage exceptions..` and change  the JavaScript priority from ALLOW to BLOCK.

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest setting for the windows

```
Settings > Advanced > Privacy and security > Site Settings > Javascript > Blocked then get switch on and off
```

Answer (score 0):

good question, i try so many way, but it is curry and boring, until i find shortcut.

1. alt + cmd + i, this open dev tools, unless you use pocket, that need set other shortcut.
2. shift + cmd + p, then input: javascript

only two shortcut, but i think safari is more convenient for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a settings in chrome

open the menu from chrome,
click settings > type in "javascript" in the search bar > click site settings > click javascript.

from here you can toggle javascript specifically to a site using their url.
or just click the big button to allow/block it to all sites.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here simply wanting to know how **to disable javascript in chrome**:

1. Right click on the website
2. Click "inspect"
3. Hit keys: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
4. Type: "Java"
5. Click "disable JavaScript"
6. Refresh page

It's from [here](https://twitter.com/RandBusiness/status/1598082797922816000?s=20&t=Hn141hPDU5Aq_R9FElSvZw)