# Why does javascript not work on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-applications

I've been facing a problem with javascript into JS page and since I'm a newbie on it I can't figure out why this code works on Firefox but not on Google Chrome.
I'd be very thankful if someone can help me with this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showFC(form) {

    var selElem = document.getElementById(form);
    var selIndex  = selElem.selectedIndex;

    document.form1.S4.options[0] = new Option("C=1",1);
    if(selIndex==0) {
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
            var val = (i+1)+0.5;
            document.form1.S4.options[i+1] = new Option(val,val);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It doesn't create dynamically elements into the select when it clicked by a button.

Here my html code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="ComputeResult">
     ... other things
     ....
     ....
   <select name="S4" id="S4" onclick="showFC('S4')">
      <option value="1">FC</option>
      <option value=""></option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: any error in console? check it.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: you sure [JavaScript is not disabled in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools)?

Comment: Show you html or create fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You're passing in `form` and then using `document.form1`.  Can you confirm that `<form id="form1">` and `<select id="S4">` exist in the page?

Comment: I added my Html code above.                                           @ Zaheer Ahmed no error man.                                            @ SajjadHashmi javascript is enabled on Chrome. I cant figure out why it doesnt work :/

Comment: I tried to run your code in a Fiddle (jsfiddle.net/tLbWk), it has a wieird behavior on Chrome indeed. First time you click on the select, it changes the values, but only has the first 2. Only when you select it a second time does it put the right values. Haven't found why just yet.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but are you sure that `document.form1` will find `<form name="form1">`?  I was under the impression that it would only work if you had `<form id="form1">`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you have two ways of declaring a function. Either you declare it like this:

```
function f() {}
```

or

```
var f = function(){}
```

The difference between the two is that the first is defined at run time, the second one at parse-time (more details here: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)).

Most probably what happened in your case, is that your function is declared after your HTML is read, and so the function does not exist. So:

```
window.showFC = function(){}
showFC = function(){}
```

should both work.

Comment: my Javascript code is between the <head> showFC() </head> of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `onclick`, use `onchange` it will work

```
<select name="S4" id="S4" onchange="showFC('S4')">
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your audio files listed in the JavaScript code MUST be named as HTTPS, not HTTP. And obviously, that means the website(s) you are linking to (including yours) must be secure. That is, you need to have your security certificates, and make sure it is activated. It's a security issue with Chrome. I hope that helps. = -)