# Why does disabling JavaScript on a page has no effect on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

On Chrome, it used to behave so that JavaScript can be immediately disabled.

For example, if the JavaScript code has something that disables highlighting text and/or copying the selected text, then if we disable JavaScript in the Developer Tools, then we can immediately select text and copy it.  (And the same goes for "right click" for the context menu to "Save Image As...").

However, since a certain version of Chrome, it became that we cannot disable JavaScript like that.  We cannot even disable JS and reload the page.  We have to go to Chrome's Settings, find JavaScript, and choose to disable JS in any page, and then reload the webpage.

Does it actually make sense that disabling JS in Dev tool will still disable the highlighting and copying?  I thought event handling is "observer pattern" and we register what function to run "on click", for example, and disabling JS should disable this event handling mechanism and therefore it is as if JS is totally turned off?  Then the current Dev tool behavior is actually incorrect?

A side item of this question, how can we quickly select text and copy, and/or right click to save images even if the page disabled it, without using any browser extension (by disabling JS or by any other method)?

(someone mentioned going to `chrome://chrome/settings/content` in the question [How to disable javascript in chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools) and it is faster, but it still requires changing global setting and reloading the page content).

Comment: ​+1 for interesting question, but close vote because most of it is primarily opinion based. You might want to make the main part just the second-to-last paragraph.