# Jump to name=key-1 when URL contains #key-1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, page-jump

I wish to jump to the selected hash whenever my URL contains a `#`.

The `#` are dynamically created and inserted into `header($location);`. Afterwards the new URL loads like this: `www.example.com?p=1#key-1`, however it wont go to the selected `#` on the page.
How can I do this?

I looked into javascript `window.location.hash`, however I couldn't figure out how to use it properly.

**UPDATE:**
The # in the url works when I manually type `#sek-31` into the adress bar. However, when I reload the same URL, I get thrown back to the top of the page.

**UPDATE TWO:**
[image]

**UPDATE THREE:**

Its working in the following browsers:

- Windows version of Safari
- Firefox
- Edge

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: How do you insert hash exactly? Are you sure there is element with ID `key-1` at time you insert hash?

Comment: @A. Wolff , I do it like this. `$location = "Location: planner_show.php?";
        $location .= "m=" . $msgId . "&p=" . $save_plan_id;
        header($location);
        die;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to `www.example.com?p=1#key-1` the browser automatically will scroll to the element with `id` key-1. So, just add a `id` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href

(This url is already demo for this. It end with `#attr-href` when you click on it you will go directly to the section `#attr-href`)

http://output.jsbin.com/bajiqu#res **Notice** that I put `#res` in the url so the browser will scroll to the `#res` paragraph.

Comment: Doesn't work... I have the address: https://example.com/planner_show.php?p=1#sek-34, and a div with the id=sek-34

Comment: Did you added `id` attribute? Did you try to go to the `Mozila` page? If so, have you noticed that you are not in the top of the page but scrolling directly to the `attr-href` section? Do you have a public URL of your site?

Comment: I have ID on my div. This id is `sek-34`. I noticed that, however, it's not the same reaction on my page. The page is a closed page. Is there any other function that could force #top?

Comment: Maybe you have a script in your site that "blocks" the scrolling. I can't know for sure until I can see your website. Try to create a fiddle that show this problem. I've added a fiddle to my answer so you can check this.

Comment: Or an `<a>` without `href` and with the desired name.

Comment: Weird. Can't seem to identify it. I have textareas and I store some information. I go to the store php file, and get redirected back unto the page with all the textareas. I then want it to select the div with, lets say, sek-34... No reactions in the URL :/

Comment: If you try to get the `www.example.com?p=1#key-1` URL directly in the browser (not via the server redirectopn). Is it work?

Comment: If I edit the webadress from lets say: `www.example.com?p=1` to `www.example.com?p=1#key-1` it works. However, if I reload the same page I just entered by hitting refresh, it doesnt.

Comment: OK, It's seems that you have a script that block the scroll on page load. If you do so after the page was loaded the scroll works. Try to run the page without `JavaScript`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: When I turn off JavaScript I dont get the value after # to display in the address bar...

Comment: I don't understand. If you change from `www.example.com?p=1` to `www.example.com?p=1#key-1`(nothing happens) then, reload the page, You still have the `#key-1` in your address bar, isn't?

Comment: When I manually change the adressbar, it works. However, when I reload the same URL after having it work the first time. It doesn't. The `#key-1` is still in the URL. With redirect it doesn't work either.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say. I'm sure that if I can see the page I will figure it out. So, when you could supply a public URL I will happy to take a look and help.

Comment: `Found` where? in your project? Or just mention a plugin? I just now noticed that the images in your question so different. Why? Where the menu in image 1 and where the content in image 2?

Comment: I pinpointed the problem to be in the chrome browser. Works perfect in Mozilla and the windows version of Safari. Edit: Also works for Edge.