# You need to enable javascript to run this app response when try to access local json file in react

Tags: reactjs, api, ecmascript-6

[image][image][image]error message I am trying to access a local .json file using fetch() like

```
fetch('fakedata.json')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('data:', data);
  })
```

But when i saw in the network it is showing

> You need to enable javascript to run this app

I check in some other pages but i cant fix this issue.
How to fix this issue

Comment: Maybe you have disabled JavaScript in your developer tools? Developer Tools -> Press `⋮` -> "Disable JavaScript"

Comment: No. i did not disable javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "local json file"? And where exactly do you see that error message?

Comment: Here i am attached error message also. Please check @Bergi

Comment: That's a weird preview for a json file. What do the *Headers* and *Response* tabs show?

Comment: for localhost preview also have the same one. please check another attached file @Bergi

Comment: @Kallis I am looking for something that is *not* just the preview but the actual raw data. In any case, this looks like your server is broken.

Comment: how to fix this @Bergi

Comment: @Kallis I can't tell without you posting more information about the server you are fetching from

Comment: what are the information you need? @Bergi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable JavaScript in chrome developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same issue and unable to get it how is it happening? @Gmv

Comment: @DevProf that was some manual error only. But, cant Remember how i fix that

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issues.

I had put the below code just after `app.use`

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

which served all the API requests directly.

Maybe this can help others facing this issue.

Comment: This was my issue too. I had the route that was no longer working directly above this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by trying to access a local json file. You can not access files on the device that runs the webpage if that is what you mean by local files. You can only access to files that are on the webserver that is serving  your applications which are in  directory of your application. I assume the second case and assume you have file called fakedata.json at the top directory of your application. In order to access that file you can use import as following:

```
import myJsonFile from "./fakedata.json"
```

If you want to use fetch to dynamically load, you should put ./ at the beginning as

```
fetch('./fakedata.json')
```

so that it fetches a file called fakedata.json which is located at the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

May be the file, `fakedata.json` is in wrong directory.
Just move the `fakedata.json` file from `src` directory to `public` directory. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I received this message when no proxy to the server was specified inside client package.json file.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

(Assuming the server was setup to listen on port 5000. In my case it also required server restart once added)

Answer (score 0):

That means, you are not getting anything from your request, it is either your json file does not exist in the directory, or there is some authentication required.
.
Try to go to the DevTools, select the Network tab,
then send your request again. If you see you're endpoint there, hover on it to see if it is pointing to the right directory..

"/fakedata.json" -points to "http://localhost/fakedata.json"
"fakedata.json" -points to a directory under "http://localhost" not necessarily a direct sub-directory... Notice the "/" at the beginning.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It's obvious from the error message in the second image that the file contains invalid JSON data. Precisely, the first character in that file is `<` which isn't valid in a JSON file.

Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
That means the first character in the file is < which isn't valid.

[image]

Comment: This error is happening because when your got the following error, the data is changed to HTML page with "you need..." content. Thats what the user is trying to fix.