# How to write automated tests for the <noscript> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, integration-testing, noscript

I'm building a webapp which falls back on a `<noscript>` tag if Javascript is disabled. I'd like to validate that that tag shows, but I'm unsure how to do that with any of the frameworks I have, or any framework in general.

The app in question by default shows the following when Javascript is disabled:

```
 <div>
  <noscript>
    <h1>Javascript Disabled</h1>
    Use this page to show content when Javascript has been disabled
  </noscript>
 </div>
```

The app replaces the above with the following when the script is loaded:

```
 <div>
   Hello World
 </div>
```

Right now for tests I'm using NightmareJS and Testem with jasmine. I don't have to be using those, but I'd like to still use Javascript if possible.

I'm completely stumped here and have no idea where I would even start - all the StackOverflow questions seem to be about how to USE `<noscript>`, and not validating it in an end-to-end or unit test (in an automated manner).

Comment: Just disable Javasctipt in the devtools and check if your noscript content is displayed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: @OlivierKrull I think the OP is talking about automatic testing.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides So then he should maybe take a look at [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), I can imagine there is a possibility to turn of Javascript in [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) and use it in the tests

Comment: I'm researching it now focusing on Chrome's WebDriver. although puppeteer should work too. Just gotta find that Chromium flag that disables JS.

Comment: W3M for markup with no js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those using Nightmare JS there is an option when creating an instance of nightmare, however some of the functions seem to fail to run (such as `evaluate`, or `exists`). In my case, I saved the page as HTML, and then verified that the HTML existed. It is also possible to save a screenshot, or pdf, to also verify the correct output.

```
const nightmare = require('nightmare')
const fs = require('fs')

const browser = nightmare({
  webPreferences: {
    javascript: false
  }
})

describe('Page with Javascript Off', () => {
  beforeAll((done) => {
    browser.goto('http://localhost:8080')
      .html('./tests/no-js-result.html', 'HTMLOnly')
      .then(() => done())
  })
  it('should show page when JS is disabled', (done) => {
    fs.readFile('./tests/no-js-result.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){
      if (err) fail('Could not read no-js-result.html')
      expect(html).toContain('<h1>Javascript Disabled</h1>')
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

[NightmareJS](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) uses [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) under the hood to run the tests which [doesn't seem to support passing a flag](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches) that disables Javascript, although I have to warn you that I didn't dig around that much.

> ... I'm using NightmareJS and Testem with jasmine. I don't have to be using those, but I'd like to still use javascript if possible.

Another solution is to use [NightwatchJS](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/) instead of NightmareJS, which is a testing framework that uses [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/home) to drive the tests which allows disabling JS by passing prefs to Chromium.

I've written a [sample project](https://github.com/nicholaswmin/nightwatch-js-disabled) as a very basic example on how to run NightwatchJS tests with JS disabled.

The project uses the following configuration to disable JS:

#### `nightwatch.json`

```
{
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "prefs" : {
            "profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above configuration, it's this particular line that is passed to Chromium which hints that we want JS disabled when NighwatchJS runs the tests:

```
"profile.managed_default_content_settings.javascript": 2
```

That being said, I'd suggest you dig a bit more thoroughly in Nightmare's documentation/issues to check if you can pass the above pref through NightmareJS instead of rewriting all your tests in NightwatchJS for this little quirk.

Comment: I'm having trouble running the sample, but I'll look into that preference for NightmareJS (to be clear, I wouldn't re-write any tests, and sooner would just have Nightwatch kick off after Nightmare). That being said, this checks out, and I'll accept this, and post if I find another solution as well.

Comment: What kind of problem are you having with the sample? Perhaps I can help.

Comment: I can run the server correctly, but when I run the nightwatch command it fails with a "Connection refused! Is selenium server started?"

https://imgur.com/a/o3QCbMs

Comment: Well did you start the selenium server using: `$ java -jar selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar`? I've mentioned in the README that you should do so.

Comment: Yeah, I have it running, (you can see in the image it running in the left terminal). All n' all, might be a moot point since I don't believe the CI servers I have will have java installed, so I'm not that focused on getting Nightwatch to work specifically.

Comment: I have never heard of a CI server that doesn't come with Selenium pre-installed and configured for you. Last note: Selenium might be running on another port. Check [NightwatchJS Getting Started](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/) on how to configure ports if you eventually go with this.

Comment: But how to combine this approach with other nightwatch tests that need JS turned on in a single application?