# How to fix "Does not provide fallback content when JavaScript is not available" in audit in PWA?

Tags: angularjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, audit, noscript

I have made a angular application and I want to test it in audit but in PWA under audit, i got error in PWA optimized section like

> Does not provide fallback content when JavaScript is not available

I have even written `<noscript>Please enable javascript</noscript>` in index.html file. I have not got this error when i ran audit in localhost by starting http-server but the same thing i am checking on server then it gives red mark in PWA optimized section? How to solve this ?

This is the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Adding the `<noscript>` block on your page would take care of this... I had gone around this myself on [my website](https://www.akberiqbal.com)

Referring to Google's site (which i visited today after your question, we see the description:

> Given these considerations, this Lighthouse audit performs a simple
>   check to ensure that your page isn't blank when JavaScript is
>   disabled. How strictly your app adheres to progressive enhancement is
>   a topic of debate, but there's widespread agreement that all pages
>   should display at least some information when JavaScript is disabled,
>   even if the content is just an alert to the user that JavaScript is
>   required to use the page.
>
> For pages that absolutely must rely on JavaScript, one approach is to
>   use a  element to alert the user that JavaScript is required
>   for the page. This is better than a blank page, because the blank page
>   leaves users uncertain about whether there's a problem with the page,
>   their browsers, or their computers.

I suspect that when you [disable javascript via chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools), you might end up with just the text "Please enable javascript"; Try also placing

- an image, a backup navigation (which runs in case of no JS only)
- a backup footer (which runs in case of no JS only)