# How to disable a specific script on load in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I've checked the answers in [How to disable JavaScript in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools)

but I'm searching to disable a specific script and the solution of blocking a specific ressource in network tab doesn't help :
[image]

because I want to block a `<script>` inside DOM

Comment: Chrome can't block inline scripts. You'll need to modify the page source by using [request interception](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getResponseBodyForInterception) in a chrome extension. There may be existing solutions. P.S. it may be easier to use Fiddler or a similar MitM proxy tool.

Comment: ^^ That.  I've used Fiddler to modify requests with custom rules before, and I'm sure you'd be able to use it to remove part of a response, in much the same way, but I've not done that.  Google will be able to help you with that - search for `Fiddler custom rules`

Comment: That said, you've blocked the js file in the image above, but not the min.js file.  What happens if you block both?

Comment: I've had to block an old owl carousel version (triggered in another module) to make sure the gliches was due to interference between version in same page, I just was curious if I had an inline script, so Thank you for MitM proxy (cuz I have linux)

Answer (score 2):

You could download AdBlock:
chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/options.html#customize

And add the script-url to the blacklist

If you want to execute the script again just disable ad block

Worked for me
Best wishes