# webscraping from tsetmc.com webpage using scrapy and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape this webpage:
http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489

here is my code: `scrapy shell "http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489"`
and I want to grab this price that I showed in the following figure (the price and the related chrome inspect are shown in the figure):
[click to show image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a07A8.jpg)

then I wrote this code `response.xpath('//*[@id="dbp]')`, but the output is:  **[ ]** .
[click to show image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvvG.jpg)

I get confused a little. Because every number that I want to select from this website, I get this error.

I will be happy if anyone can help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to extract javascript dynamically loaded data because javascript can not run in scrapy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=42354736493447489')
time.sleep(5) # delay 5 sec
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
# print(soup.prettify())
prices = soup.find('div', {'class': 'box6 h80'}).find('table')

for td in prices.find_all('tr')[1]:
    print(td.getText()) # all td text garbed.

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks a lot for your response and for writing the code.
How did you recognize that this is javascript?
you use beautifulsoup and selenium. should I learn both of them in order to extract data from the website?

Comment: Disable JavaScript from network dev tool, You may follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools to do that. You will see the page will not load properly. to extract the javascript related content you have to learn selenium.