# web scraping with rvest in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to extract the impact ranking table in tidy for with columns rank, university name, SDG goal 1, SDG goal 2, SDG goal 3, SDG goal 4, and overall score, country. Following is the code that I tried.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

link <- "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/impactrankings"
selector <- "#block-system-main > div > div.container"
webpage <- read_html(link)
data <- html_nodes(webpage, selector)
content <- html_text(data)

content
```

The above code did not serve my purpose. I am trying to extract data from a university impact ranking table on a web page and organize it into a tidy format.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help to define what you mean by "did not serve my purpose". If you mean that no table rows were returned although the selector looks correct, the most usual reason for that is dynamically-generated content which is not accessible by rvest. In this case you need to use a tool such as [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) or [chromote](https://github.com/rstudio/chromote).

Answer (score 1):

The general reminder for rvest questions applies: before using rvest, try [temporarily blocking Javascript in your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405383/how-to-disable-javascript-in-chrome-developer-tools) and reloading the page. If the information you're wanting doesn't appear, the information very likely is loaded with Javascript, so rvest isn't the tool for the job.

The fall back options are:

- hope to luck out and see a JSON file in the Network tab of the Inspector
- or using Selenium.

In this case, we were lucky:

[image: screenshot of end product of steps below, with the json file appearing in the inspector]

The file we want is the one beginning with `world_impact_rankings`. We can get the URL the following way:

1. Open the webpage in our browser (the screenshot is of Chrome, but it's the same with others)
2. Right click on the page anywhere, and open "Inspect". Something should have just popped up, probably at the bottom of your browser window
3. Within that new area (the inspector), there should be a Network tab at the top of it, like in my screenshot. Open that
4. In my experience, you always have to reload the page, to get the Network tab to start listing network requests, so reload the page. You should now see many requests be logged.
5. Filter the requests to only the ones with JSON files by using the filter search box in the top left
6. Find the request you are looking for, right click on it > Copy > Copy link address (it might say Copy URL if you use Firefox, it's all the same)

Now we have the URL, we can use JSONlite to load it into R:

```
# (install if necessary, and) load jsonlite
pacman::p_load(jsonlite)


# it's best for you to do this yourself, as 1. the links are likely going to change into the future, and 2. it's best if I don't spoonfeed you everything! :-)
link <- "insert your link here"

# load the data
data <- fromJSON(link)

names(data) # [1] "data"      "subjects"  "locations" "pillars"
```

The JSON file includes four different sets of data: "subjects", which seems like it is a named list of subjects and their corresponding codes, "locations" (some kind of id for each country), "pillars" (perhaps internal model data, and "data", which is everything else, and the data you are looking for.

```
df <- data$data |> dplyr::as_tibble() # I used as_tibble() here because R's default way of displaying a dataframe is to print the entire thing, which is a bit of a mess when it has 1591 rows and 22 columns, as in the example below. R knows not to print every row nor every column of a tibble, but converting it to a tibble() isn't strictly necessary
df
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1,591 × 22
   rank_order rank  name          scores_overall scores_overall_rank record_type
   <chr>      <chr> <chr>         <chr>          <chr>               <chr>      
 1 1          1     Western Sydn… 99.4           1                   master_acc…
 2 2          2     University o… 97.5           2                   master_acc…
 3 3          3     Queen’s Univ… 97.2           3                   master_acc…
 4 4          4     Universiti S… 96.9           4                   master_acc…
 5 5          5     University o… 96.6           5                   master_acc…
 6 6          6     Arizona Stat… 96.5           6                   public     
 7 7          =7    University o… 96.4           7                   master_acc…
 8 8          =7    RMIT Univers… 96.4           8                   master_acc…
 9 9          =9    Aalborg Univ… 95.8           9                   master_acc…
10 10         =9    University o… 95.8           10                  master_acc…
# ℹ 1,581 more rows
# ℹ 16 more variables: member_level <chr>, url <chr>, nid <int>,
#   location <chr>, stats_number_students <chr>,
#   stats_student_staff_ratio <chr>, stats_pc_intl_students <chr>,
#   stats_female_male_ratio <chr>, aliases <chr>, subjects_offered <chr>,
#   best_scores <chr>, closed <lgl>, unaccredited <lgl>, disabled <lgl>,
#   apply_link <chr>, cta_button <df[,2]>
```

The dataframe above is for just the overall ranking. To do it for the other ones, since it's only four others, it's easy to get those by repeating the above process. If you were doing it on every SDG, then I would suggest automating the process (the URL is found in some JSON on the site, so you could scrape the URL (e.g. like in margusl's answer), and then repeat the above process).

One note re: your question - you said:

> *"I want to extract the impact ranking table in tidy for with columns rank, university name, SDG goal 1, SDG goal 2, SDG goal 3, SDG goal 4, and overall score, country."*.

I presume this is for an assignment? If yes, you might want to talk with your instructors to ask them if they understand what tidy data actually means, because what they're asking for, having information like SDG number stored in the names of columns isn't it. Tidying this data would mean keeping the data long, and adding an SDG number column, with it being "Overall" for the above data, and the number for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Actual table data is delivered as JSON, which in turn includes HTML snippets for top SGD ranks and scores. We can first extract the URL of that JSON from page source and then parse HTML to extract SGD data:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# extract SGD values from html, returns list of lists for every record:
# List of 4
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ rnk: chr "5"
# ..$ val: chr "80.3"
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ rnk: chr "12"
# ..$ val: chr "93.4"
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ rnk: chr "15"
# ..$ val: chr "96.7"
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ rnk: chr "17"
# ..$ val: chr "98.8"
parse_sgd_row <- function(html){
  read_html(html) %>% 
    html_elements(".sdg-score-multi__item") %>% 
    map(\(sdg_item) list(rnk  = html_element(sdg_item, ".sdg-score-multi__number") %>% html_text2(),
                         val = html_element(sdg_item, ".sdg-score-multi__value") %>% html_text2()))
}

# extract url of the JSON that hold table content
# ( extract part of embedded js code and parse it as JSON )
json_url <- read_html("https://www.timeshighereducation.com/impactrankings") %>% 
  html_elements("script") %>% 
  pluck(10) %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_split("\n") %>% 
  pluck(1) %>% 
  str_subset(fixed("function init_drupal_core_settings()")) %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=Drupal.settings, ).*(?=\\)\\;)") %>% 
  jsonlite::parse_json() %>% 
  pluck("the_data_rankings", "#datatable-1", "ajax", "url")
json_url
#> [1] "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/sites/default/files/the_data_rankings/world_impact_rankings_2023_0_en_a9364380c7df0f3c145f81db79c61be3.json"

# extract table from JSON
ranking <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_url)$data %>% as_tibble()
glimpse(ranking)
#> Rows: 1,591
#> Columns: 22
#> $ rank_order                <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",…
#> $ rank                      <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "=7", "=7", "=…
#> $ name                      <chr> "Western Sydney University", "University of …
#> $ scores_overall            <chr> "99.4", "97.5", "97.2", "96.9", "96.6", "96.…
#> $ scores_overall_rank       <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",…
#> $ record_type               <chr> "master_account", "master_account", "master_…
#> $ member_level              <chr> "0", "6", "11", "0", "0", "11", "0", "0", "1…
#> $ url                       <chr> "/world-university-rankings/western-sydney-u…
#> $ nid                       <int> 1014, 512, 639, 131486, 808, 591, 564, 915, …
#> $ location                  <chr> "Australia", "United Kingdom", "Canada", "Ma…
#> $ stats_number_students     <chr> "36,033", "37,035", "26,556", "23,492", "18,…
#> $ stats_student_staff_ratio <chr> "40.3", "14.2", "26.2", "11.6", "22.9", "19.…
#> $ stats_pc_intl_students    <chr> "22%", "44%", "17%", "17%", "36%", "17%", "2…
#> $ stats_female_male_ratio   <chr> "58 : 42", "55 : 45", "59 : 41", "64 : 36", …
#> $ aliases                   <chr> "Western Sydney University University of Wes…
#> $ subjects_offered          <chr> "Civil Engineering,Geology, Environmental, E…
#> $ best_scores               <chr> "<a role=\"button\" class=\"sdg-score-multi_…
#> $ closed                    <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FA…
#> $ unaccredited              <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FA…
#> $ disabled                  <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FA…
#> $ apply_link                <chr> NA, "https://www.timeshighereducation.com/st…
#> $ cta_button                <df[,2]> <data.frame[26 x 2]>

# work with a subset of columns,
# switch to rowwise to parse each individual html snippet in 
# best_scores column to extacr SGD values;
# quite a slow process, test with first 10 rows
ranking[1:10,] %>% 
  select(rank_order, rank, name, scores_overall, location, best_scores) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sgd = parse_sgd_row(best_scores) %>% list(), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  unnest_wider(sgd, names_sep = ".") %>% 
  unnest_wider(starts_with("sgd"), names_sep = ".")
```

Resulting frame for first 10 rows:

```r
#> # A tibble: 10 × 13
#>    rank_order rank  name   scores_overall location sgd.1.rnk sgd.1.val sgd.2.rnk
#>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>          <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#>  1 1          1     Weste… 99.4           Austral… 5         80.3      12       
#>  2 2          2     Unive… 97.5           United … 15        97.4      12       
#>  3 3          3     Queen… 97.2           Canada   2         90.6      16       
#>  4 4          4     Unive… 96.9           Malaysia 16        94.1      2        
#>  5 5          5     Unive… 96.6           Austral… 13        92.8      15       
#>  6 6          6     Arizo… 96.5           United … 15        95.4      14       
#>  7 7          =7    Unive… 96.4           Canada   9         99.4      2        
#>  8 8          =7    RMIT … 96.4           Austral… 10        92.1      8        
#>  9 9          =9    Aalbo… 95.8           Denmark  4         90.6      10       
#> 10 10         =9    Unive… 95.8           Canada   11        91.8      13       
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: sgd.2.val <chr>, sgd.3.rnk <chr>, sgd.3.val <chr>,
#> #   sgd.4.rnk <chr>, sgd.4.val <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>