# how could `if (console == undefined)` break js execution?

Tags: javascript, console

When I edit production code (little fixes) I want to add `console.log` for example, but not to break page for users who don't have firebug or don't use chrome I decide to redefine console object:

```
if (console == undefined) {
    console = {
        log     : function(){},
        info    : function(){},
        warn    : function(){},
        error   : function(){}
    };
};
```

After I inserted this code, JS-execution was broken in browsers that don't have console object (IE, firefox without firebug, etc). (By "broken" I mean that code after these lines doesn't execute at all)
Why did it happen?

Comment: Define "broken" and "it". My telepathy is in the garage.

Comment: code that is after these lines just doesn't execute. Sorry, I edited my post (was in hurry)

Comment: @Tomalak this is an obvouis problem. You should be able to understand it. I expected better :(

Comment: @Raynos: If nothing else, the OP needs to learn how to ask better questions. Yes, I could guess at what the OP means, but that doesn't make the question any better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(console == undefined)`

will throw a `ReferenceError` if console is undefined.

Use `typeof` instead which does not throw `ReferenceErrors` for undeclared variables

`(typeof console === "undefined")`

Comment: I created a console stub for these situations. Check it out at https://github.com/robertofrega/console-stub

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if ( window.console === undefined ) {

    window.console = {
        // Your methods
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeap, it works! But I posted in plain javascript (without function encapsulation) - so I was already in global scope (in browser it's window). Why doesn't `console` work, but exactly `window.console` ?

Comment: @Innuendo: as Raynos's post says, it will throw a ReferenceError if `console` hasn't been declared. If you use `window.console`, then it just returns `undefined`, like accessing a non-existent property of any object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really good to compare a variable to `undefined`, since `undefined` is a simple undefined variable.

You can use something like this:

```
if (!window.console)
  console = {
    log   : function(){},
    info  : function(){},
    warn  : function(){},
    error : function(){}
  };
```

Edit: I just found this: [How do I print debug messages in the Google Chrome JavaScript Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-to-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console/2757552#2757552)

Answer (score 1):

If console is not defined in the js then it will throw an error instead use typeof to check the variable's existense

```
if (typeof console == 'undefined') { }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `if(console == undefined)` to `if(window.console == undefined)` everything will work

Answer (score 1):

Any of the answer above should work fine.

One note: You might also add "dir" to your list of empty methods, since people sometimes use `console.dir()` to print out objects.