# how show a message whenever javascript is going to execute?

Tags: javascript

i want track error in my javascript code.Some times javascript automatically executes and hangs my browser i want to track which part of javascript is executing automatically and hangs ....

Comment: Use any javascript debugger: FF firebug, chrome developer tools, ...

Comment: ... for example the JavaScript Console in Chrome or FireBug for Firefox

Comment: thax for reply.. but whenever page is going hang javascript console not showing any thing...

Comment: it may be best for us to see your code...

Comment: Put many `console.log` in suspicious parts of your code. Then look at console and you will be able to tell when JavaScript hangs.

Answer (score 0):

For tracking errors using console.log

Or use an alert as your first line of code with the variable's inside it and this should help,

I would recommend console.log as alerts become annoying, Console log also makes it easier to view variables, objects and arrays. I personally use chrome you should try it :)

This might also help [Console log question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-to-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console)