# Is there a toString-like function for javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, debugging

While debugging and developing with javascript, I often wanted to alert the objects, so I used the below code:

```
for(a in obj)
{
  alert(a +' = '+obj[a])
}
```

It serves well, but it is too annoying. I want to know if there is anything just like this for arrays:

```
var temp = ['a','b','c'];
alert(temp); // it will alert a,b,c
```

So what I wish to do is:

```
var temp = {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'};
alert(temp) ; // It should alert json {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'}
```

Or any other better suggestion so I could look up the object easily.

Comment: How about `alert(JSON.stringify(temp));`?

Comment: @JamesAllardice yes it is good one but I want to extend the object definition. How it has been done in case of array that they are alerted like strings ?

Comment: @RupeshPatel - The way it's done with arrays is an internal part of the language. It's documented in detail in the ECMAScript specification. The same is not true of objects. You can overwrite the `Object.prototype.toString` method, or you can call another function as shown in various answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alert calls toString, so you can overwrite toString for debugging purposes:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
};
```

So you can just call `alert(foo);` and it will display the JSON representation of foo

Comment: Oh my my how I have ignored this thing. Thanks any way :)

Comment: And hopefully in your code base someone is not doing bad object detection and you break it be overriding toString globally.

Comment: @epascarello for me  it is just for debugging purpose commenting two lines after finishing wont any matter. thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(temp)) ;
```

instead of

```
alert(temp) ;
```

Comment: yes it is good one but can I make some thing just like array so alert(temp) can work. so all the objects can share the method whenever they are alerted.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this so the alerted format can be as you want

```
 Object.prototype.toString = function{
    var str='';
    for(a in this)
    {
      str+=a +' = '+obj[a]);
    }    
    }
```

Comment: it is also a good suggestions I guess I should go this way thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript reference guide says there is a toString method for javascript Objects, see the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

It is on the mozilla developer page but I believe that should be what you need. excerpt is here, "
var o = new Object();
o.toString(); "

Comment: The question is asking about objects, not arrays.

Comment: sorry I understand what you meant now the line, "I want to know if there is anything just like for arrays" confused me. Sorry

Comment: edited for what I found. there are a few other methods to go along with those, "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object" this page has them

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

[dump() - Javascript equivalent of PHP's print_r() function](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php)

Perl provides Data::Dumper for work like this. Perfect for situations like this. Great for debugging.

A better approach is using JSON.stringify:

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, 4); // Indented 4 spaces
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2,c:{d:1,e:[1,2]}}, null, "\t"); // Indented with tab
```

Ref: [How Can I Beautify JSON Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614862/how-can-i-beautify-json-programmatically)

And alert() will only cause you more grief, start using console log. They are persistent and allows you to refer to the output more consistently.

Ref: [How to Print Debug Messages in the google chrome javascript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-to-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console)

Better yet: Use a JavaScript debugger to analyse your objects. This is generally a better experience than simply printing or alertingthings out. But console logs are generally better if you have to do this in many locations.

Ref: [How do you launch the javascript debugger in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

> *Or any other better suggestion so I could look up the object easily.*

Most good browsers' console will let you drill down into an object if you log it. For example, with Chrome:

```
console.log(obj);
```

Will log a tree-view object to the console.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

```
function dump(arr,level) {
    var dumped_text = "";

    if(!level) level = 0;
    var level_padding = "";

    for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++)
        level_padding += "    ";

    var type = typeof(arr);

    if (arr === null){
        dumped_text = "null";
    } else if (arr instanceof Array) {
        dumped_text += "[";

        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];
            dumped_text += dump (value, level+1) + ',';
        }

        if(dumped_text.length > 1)
            dumped_text = dumped_text.substring (0, dumped_text.length-1);
        dumped_text += "]";
    } else if(type == 'object') {
        dumped_text += "{\n";

        for(var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];
            dumped_text += level_padding + item + " : ";
            dumped_text += dump(value,level+1) + ',\n';
        }

        if(dumped_text.length > 2)
            dumped_text = dumped_text.substring (0, dumped_text.length-2);

        dumped_text += "\n" + level_padding.substring (0, level_padding.length-4) + "}";
    } else if (type == 'string'){
        dumped_text = "'" + arr + "'";
    } else if (type == 'number'){
        dumped_text = arr + "";
    } else if (type == 'boolean'){
        dumped_text = arr + "";
    }
 return dumped_text;
}
```