# JavaScript document doesn't change after function call

Tags: javascript, html, document

I'm trying to build a simple HTML5 music player with JavaScript.
I've build a player with this code:

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source id="song" src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

I've build a couple of `<a>` which call function changeSong(n);

```
function changeSong(n) {
    document.getElementById("song").src = "song" + n + ".mp3";
}
```

and when I click the `<a>`'s nothing happens to the document, and it won't work..

The `<a>`'s:

```
<a href="#1" onclick="changeSong(1)">Play song 1 </a></br>
<a href="#2" onclick="changeSong(2)">Play song 2 </a>
```

What do to make it work?
////

I tried just running the JavaScript w/o function and it works. but when it's called from the  as a function it doesn't...

Comment: your function signature is `changeSong` but you are calling `playSong`

Comment: Did you even preview the question if it is readable?

Comment: Where is the code for playSong()

Comment: I accidentally called playSong insetad if changeSong, I fixed that but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user1050389 Step through the code by [using a debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/66420/344480).

Answer (score 1):

#### Change:

```
<a href="#2" onclick="playSong(2)">Play song 2 </a>
```

#### With:

```
<a href="#2" onclick="changeSong(2)">Play song 2 </a>
```

Is that a typo?

---

#### Actually, it works in the `console`:

```
document.getElementById("song");
<source id=​"song" src=​"horse.ogg" type=​"audio/​ogg">​
document.getElementById("song").src;
"chrome://newtab/horse.ogg"
document.getElementById("song").src = 'Hi.ogg';
"Hi.ogg"
document.getElementById("song").src;
"chrome://newtab/Hi.ogg"
```

Comment: I'm not using any console, I'm just writing the code in Notepad++ and using Chrome to see it..

Answer (score 0):

You miss the name of the method in the call. This works:

```
<a href="#1" onclick="changeSong(1)">Play song 1 </a></br>
<a href="#2" onclick="changeSong(2)">Play song 2 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your goal ? Do not tell me that you are trying to call the

```
changeSong(1)
```

on the "Play song 1" click.

just by reading your code I can say that change

```
<a href="#2" onclick="playSong(2)">Play song 2 </a>
```

by

```
<a href="#2" onclick="changeSong(2)">Play song 2 </a>
```

Or I'm missing something :/

Can you add some debug code into the

```
changeSong(n){
    document.getElementById("song").src="song"+n+".mp3";
}
```

an tell us if something is appening :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just using the browser.. I have no Idea how to debug

Comment: what king of browser are you using? there is a large amount of addons to help you to debug your js code.
For exemple: 
Firefox [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)
Chrome [console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)
IE [tutorial](http://berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/)

Comment: Follow this link, you will learn how to debug with Chrome [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217957/how-to-print-debug-messages-in-the-google-chrome-javascript-console)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with HTML5 , but I can find two errors.

1. You're calling playSong instead of changeSong
2. You should declare that changeSong is a function:

   ```
   function changeSong(n){
       document.getElementById("song").src = "song" + n + ".mp3";
   }
   ```